# why does the $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] not return MSIE

Tags: php, browser

I am trying to do some php browser testing. When I looked at

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'
```

I found that it returned this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

even though I was on IE 11.

When I was on Chrome, it returned this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36
```

Which makes more sense. Why is there no MSIE in the IE, and how can I target it?

Comment: with the Trident tag. Its the IE engine. Check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(v=vs.85).aspx and also this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_(layout_engine)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browser_engines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

["Trident"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_(layout_engine)) is the layout engine for MSIE 11.  As you can see there, while you were on IE 11 it loaded as `Trident/7.0; rv:11.0)`  Just like when you were on Chrome it loaded as `AppleWebKit/537.36`.

If you're looking to get more information about the browser, you could always use PHP's [get_browser()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) function.

Comment: technically, its the layout engine from MSIE8

Comment: @oPi, you're right.  However, it's still listed as being a part of IE11 in the ["Versions"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_(layout_engine)#Versions) section of the Wikipedia page.

Comment: LOL, it was my bad. I read "is the layout engine from MSIE 11". Sorry

Answer (score 1):

its because the MSIE from 8 marks its version through TRIDENT. Ive found this script time ago. It also detects if the browser is in compatibility mode. It may help you, but its in JS:

**EDIT**: a simple search made i found the original code in [github](https://gist.github.com/nross63/10408445).

```
var ieUserAgent = {
    init: function () {
        // Get the user agent string
        var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        this.compatibilityMode = false;
        // Detect whether or not the browser is IE
        var ieRegex = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
        if (ieRegex.exec(ua) == null)
            this.exception = "The user agent detected does not contain Internet Explorer.";

        // Get the current "emulated" version of IE
        this.renderVersion = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
        this.version = this.renderVersion;

        // Check the browser version with the rest of the agent string to detect compatibility mode
        if (ua.indexOf("Trident/7.0") > -1) {
            if (ua.indexOf("MSIE 7.0") > -1) {
                this.compatibilityMode = true;
            }
            this.version = 11;                  // IE 11
        }
        else if (ua.indexOf("Trident/6.0") > -1) {
            if (ua.indexOf("MSIE 7.0") > -1) {
                this.compatibilityMode = true;
            }
            this.version = 10;                  // IE 10
        }
        else if (ua.indexOf("Trident/5.0") > -1) {      
            if (ua.indexOf("MSIE 7.0") > -1) {
                this.compatibilityMode = true;
            }
            this.version = 9;                   // IE 9
        }
        else if (ua.indexOf("Trident/4.0") > -1) {
            if (ua.indexOf("MSIE 7.0") > -1) {
                this.compatibilityMode = true;
            }
            this.version = 8;                   // IE 8
        }
        else if (ua.indexOf("MSIE 7.0") > -1)
            this.version = 7;                   // IE 7
        else
            this.version = 6;                   // IE 6
    }
};

// Initialize the ieUserAgent object
ieUserAgent.init();

$(document).ready(function() {
    if(ieUserAgent.compatibilityMode) {
        //do stuff
    }
    if(ieUserAgent.version == 6) {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

IE11 drops the "MSIE" portion of the user agent string. It doesn't stop there, either - `navigator.appName` will return `Netscape` and `navigator.product` returns `Gecko`.

The likely cause for this is that IE11 has caught up enough with modern web standards that Microsoft doesn't want it triggering the old `if(IE) { // shitty simpler website }` handlers all over the web. They want it seeing the same full-featured version Chrome/Firefox see.

Comment: No no they've being doing this since well before IE caught up with _any_ web standards. See the dupe.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit They've been adding stuff for years, but removing the key `MSIE` bit is new in 11.